# Copy and paste automatically on cell change using private sub

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add an archive sheet to my workbook where closed tickets are collected. I would like the row of a particular ticket to be cut from a sheet labeled 'Tickets' and pasted into a sheet labeled 'Archive' once its status has changed from open to closed. I would like this to happen using a private sub so that it happens on cell change. The Status is found in column 4.

If that is possible im assuming it will be possible to do it the other way round too. So if a ticket is re-opened again and its status is changed in the 'Archive' sheet it will be cut and paste back into the 'Tickets' sheet.

This is the code we have so far. We can seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range) 

If Target.Column = 4 Then 
If Target.Value = "Closed" Then
   R = Target.Row 
   Rows(R).Cut 
   Worksheets("Archive").Select
     With ActiveSheet
      lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Row
     End With
   Cells(lastrow,1).Select
   Selection.Paste
End If
End If 
End sub
```

Comment: it comes up with a debug error and highlights Cells(lastrow, 1).Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just making small amendments to your current code:

```
If Target.Column = 4 Then
If Target.Value = "Closed" Then
   R = Target.Row
   Rows(R).Cut
   Worksheets("sheet3").Select
     With ActiveSheet
      lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
      .Cells(lastrow, 1).Select
      .Paste
     End With
End If
End If
```

Comment: I think the main problem was the ".Cells" whereas you only put "Cells"